# antlr4 - conflicting rules, how to fix

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have the following rules:

```
property   : NAME;
value      : STRING | NUMBER;

NUMBER     : ('0'..'9')+;
NAME       : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9' | '-' | '_')+;
STRING     : '"' (~'"')* '"';
```

When a property is a number, ANTLR says:

```
line 1:14 mismatched input '5' expecting NAME
```

I understand why this happens. The `NUMBER` rule is mentioned before the `NAME` rule, so it has precedence. The number is recognized by the `NUMBER` rule.

What is the common way to handle this in ANTLR? I could rewrite the `property` rule as following, but I don't really know if it is a good idea, as I am introducing redundancy.

```
property   : NAME | NUMBER;
```

Re-ordering `NUMBER` and `NAME` isn't a good idea either, as it will break the `value` rule for numbers (same problem).

Important to note: I am fairly new to ANTLR and am still learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `property   : NAME | NUMBER;` is the way to do it.

Comment: Thanks! I have to get used that defining redundant right sides (`NUMBER` is a subset of `NAME`) is preferred.